# Embed product-variance logic into Django models

Tags: django, orm, python-2.7

I wonder how I would model my Products model to auto-create (and that the admin-App would also understand it) variants of a Product based on it's variant-parts.

My Products have;

- Colors
- Sizes

and can probably get more features in the future.

How would I model my Product class to generate all variants of the Product?

Say I would create a new Product in Colors `Red` `Blue` `Green` and in Sizes `XS` `S` `M` `L` `XL`.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Color(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Size(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class FutureVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# etc.
```

Now when I would need a smart method that when I would auto-create all color-size-[FUTURE VARIANT] for that product.

So I would tell Django;

- Create new Product

  - In the colors `Red` `Blue` `Green`
  - In the sizes `XS` `S` `M` `L` `XL`

And the Product class would go and produce Products with all possible combinations in the products_product table.

I'm almost sure that this has design flaws. But I'm just curious how to put this logic in the ORM, and not to write weird procedural code, which would probably go against the DRY principal.

In Database logic I would think of something like this;

```
PRODUCTS
- id
- name

PRODUCTS_VARIANTS_COLORS
- id
- name
- html_code

PRODUCTS_VARIANTS_SIZES
- id
- name

PRODUCTS_VARIANTS_TABLES
- table_name
- table_id

PRODUCTS_VARIANTS
- product_id
- variant_table
- variant_id
```

This way I could make endless variant tables, as long as I would register them in my `PRODUCTS_VARIANTS_TABLES` and store their name as relevant. `PRODUCTS_VARIANTS` would hold all the the variants of the product, including combinations of them all. I am also aiming to have a selection-phase where the user can chose (in a HTML checkbox-list) which variants it does and doesn't want.

The problem (I think) is that this would not really comply with a logic in the ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you are asking about alternatives or just looking to make your way work, but what about splitting a product from it's attributes?

So instead of having separate models for attributes, you just have an `Attribute` model. This way you are future-proofing your database so you can easily add more attributes (like if you have products with a height and width instead of just color or size).

```
class AttributeBase(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255) # e.g. color, size, shape, etc.
    ...

class Attribute(models.Model):
    base = models.ForeignKey('AttributeBase', related_name='attributes')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255) # e.g. red, L, round, etc.
    internal_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True) # other values you may need e.g. #ff0000, etc.
    ...

class ProductAttribute(Attribute):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='attributes')
```

It now becomes very easy to create all attributes for a product...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...

    def add_all_attributes(self):
        for attribute in Attribute.objects.all():
            self.attributes.add(attribute)
```

now when you use `product.add_all_attributes()` that product will contain every attribute. AND you can even make it add attributes of a certain `AttributeBase`

```
def add_all_attributes_for_base(self, label):
    base = AttributeBase.objects.get(label=label)
    for attribute in base.attributes.all():
        self.attributes.add(attribute)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write something as:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    @classmethod
    def create_variants(cls):
        # compute all possible combinations
        combinations = ...
        for combination in combinations:
            Product.objects.create(**combination)
```

Creating all the combinations would indeed happen through registering the possible variants and their possible values.

Note that ORM is there to help you map Django objects to database records, it doesn't help you with producing the database records (read: Django models) that you wish to save.